# row.operator() pass an argument to the called function

Tags: scripting, operator, panel

I had this working for Blender 2.x long ago but I'm unable to get that old script to work in 3.x and 4.x.
All I want to do is create a panel with buttons. The buttons, when clicked, do execute the same function but with different ('hardcoded') parameters.

How it worked for 2.x:

```
class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = 'VIEW3D_PT_MyPanel'
    bl_label = "MyPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        ob = context.object
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("vhsl.selectbygroupname", text = 'sel. group 1').param = 'tngrp1'
        row.operator("vhsl.selectbygroupname", text = 'sel. group 2').param = 'tngrp2'
        row.operator("vhsl.selectbygroupname", text = 'sel. group 3').param = 'tngrp3'

class OpSelectByGroupName(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "vhsl.selectbygroupname"
    bl_label = "Select by Group name"
    param = bpy.props.StringProperty()
    def execute(self, context):
        print('Button OpSelectByGroupName clicked')
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT') #Deselecting all
        bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_set_active(group=self.param)
        bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_select()        
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

When executed in 3.x or 4.x it results in:

```
AttributeError: 'VHSL_OT_selectbygroupname' object has no attribute 'param'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can´t see the inputs in dialog box- blender 2.93](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/224545/can%c2%b4t-see-the-inputs-in-dialog-box-blender-2-93)